# Compilation error trying to bind factory class in Jersey 2.27

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, jersey

I'm building a Java REST API with Jersey 2.27 and in my test class (as shown below) I get the following compile error: `Cannot resolve method 'bindFactory(java.lang.Class<LdapServiceFactory>)'`.

I don't get why this is not compiling. The `bindFactory`method has one parameter of type `Class<? extends Supplier<T>>`, and my factory class is implementing `Supplier<LdapService>` as shown below. Can someone explain to me why this won't compile?

*PS: Tthese are only snippets of the full code to make things clearer.*

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder;

public class AppTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .packages(App.class.getPackage().getName())
                .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                    @Override
                    protected void configure() {
                        bindFactory(LdapServiceFactory.class).to(LdapService.class);
                    }
            });
    }
}
```

Here is what my `LdapServiceFactory` class looks like:

```
public class LdapServiceFactory<T> implements Supplier<LdapService> {
    @Override
    public LdapService<T> get() {
        return createLdapService(DEFAULT_PROPERTIES_FILE);
    }
}
```

And, finally, the `LdapService` class:

```
public interface LdapService<T> {
    List<T> request(String filter, String[] attributes, ResponseHandler<T> responseHandler) throws FilterException, ServerException;
}
```

Comment: `LdapServiceFactory<T>`. Why the generic? Doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Because I want to pass different object mappers to the request method. For example I can do `ldapService.request(myFilter, myAttributes, Employee::create)` when quering for an employee or I can do `ldapService.request(myFilter, myAttributes, Location::create)` when searching for locations.

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense, as you are never going to actually create the factory yourself. So when are you every going to be able to pass a generic type to it? The Generic type should go in the `to()` binding. You can use `to(new GenericType<LdapService<YourType>>(){})`. And the Generic should go in the `Supplier<LdapService<YourType>>`

Comment: The code compiled once I removed the generic type on the factory class. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the generic type from your factory class. What you're supposed to be going is adding the concrete type to the `Supplier`

```
public class LdapServiceFactory implements Supplier<LdapService<YourType>> {
    @Override
    public LdapService<YourType> get() {
        return createLdapService(DEFAULT_PROPERTIES_FILE);
    }
}
```

Then when you bind it, do

```
bindFactory(LdapServiceFactory.class)
        .to(new GenericType<LdapService<YourType>>() {});
```

This ensures the type safety when you inject it.

```
@Inject
private LdapService<YourType> service;
```